# CNN-LSTM model predicting same results for everything?

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, conv-neural-network, lstm

I am currently working on a simple ML model to predict the next n number of 'Close' price in a stock market. The idea is to apply a CNN-LSTM to do this.

Dataset:

```
            Open    High    Low     Close
Date                
2020-06-30  90.02   91.50   90.00   91.20
2020-07-01  91.28   91.84   90.98   91.03
2020-07-02  91.96   92.62   90.91   91.03
2020-07-06  92.50   93.95   92.47   93.46
2020-07-07  93.85   94.66   93.06   93.17
```

After splitting the dataset array:

```
x-train = (189, 7, 4)
y-train = (189,) #contains 'Close' column
x-test = (49, 7, 4)
y-test = (49,)
```

The model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(filters=64,
                           kernel_size=5,
                           padding="same",
                           activation="relu",
                           input_shape=(x_train.shape[1],x_train.shape[2])),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(pool_size=1),
    tf.keras.layers.LSTM(28, return_sequences=False),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
])

model.compile(loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError(),
              optimizer='adam',
              metrics=['mae'])
model.summary()

Model: "sequential_3"
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv1d_3 (Conv1D)            (None, 7, 64)             1344      
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling1d_3 (MaxPooling1 (None, 7, 64)             0         
_________________________________________________________________
lstm_3 (LSTM)                (None, 28)                10416     
_________________________________________________________________
dense_4 (Dense)              (None, 1)                 29        
=================================================================
Total params: 11,789
Trainable params: 11,789
Non-trainable params: 0
```

The model fit:

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, 
                    batch_size=1, 
                    epochs=200,
                    validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

Epoch 1/200
189/189 [==============================] - 5s 11ms/step - loss: 13459.2314 - mae: 115.5125 - val_loss: 15005.9795 - val_mae: 122.4439
Epoch 2/200
189/189 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 12546.2568 - mae: 111.4981 - val_loss: 14059.5391 - val_mae: 118.5161
Epoch 3/200
189/189 [==============================] - 1s 6ms/step - loss: 11779.1270 - mae: 107.9996 - val_loss: 13299.4736 - val_mae: 115.2649
Epoch 4/200
189/189 [==============================] - 1s 7ms/step - loss: 11100.7578 - mae: 104.8154 - val_loss: 12585.6465 - val_mae: 112.1257
Epoch 5/200
189/189 [==============================] - 1s 8ms/step - loss: 10459.3828 - mae: 101.7052 - val_loss: 11904.8115 - val_mae: 109.0474
...
Epoch 200/200
189/189 [==============================] - 2s 8ms/step - loss: 114.0937 - mae: 8.2172 - val_loss: 92.8458 - val_mae: 8.9090
```

Performance:

```
Median Absolute Error (MAE): 8.91
Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE): 6.83 %
Median Absolute Percentage Error (MDAPE): 6.0 %
```

The prediction:

```
y_pred = model.predict(x_test)
```

Predicted result:

```
array([[120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669],
       [120.17669]], dtype=float32)
```

I am at a loss here. I tried playing with the model parameters but the predicted results were either the same or it returns nothing. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Added how I obtain my train/test dataset:

```
train = dataset[:196]
test = dataset[196:252]

# Make dataframe into array for input
train = array(train)
test = array(test)

def partition_dataset(sequence_length, data):
    x, y = [], []
    data_len = data.shape[0]
    for i in range(sequence_length, data_len):
        x.append(data[i-sequence_length:i,:]) #contains sequence_length values 0-sequence_length * columsn
        y.append(data[i, index_Close]) #contains the prediction values for validation,  for single-step prediction
    
    # Convert the x and y to numpy arrays
    x = np.array(x)
    y = np.array(y)
    return x, y

# Second step : create train_x and train_y
timestep = 7
index_Close = dataset.columns.get_loc("Close")

x_train, y_train = partition_dataset(timestep, train)
x_test, y_test = partition_dataset(timestep, test)

print(f"x-train = {x_train.shape}")
print(f"y-train = {y_train.shape}")
print(f"x-test = {x_test.shape}")
print(f"y-test = {y_test.shape}")

x-train = (189, 7, 4)
y-train = (189,)
x-test = (49, 7, 4)
y-test = (49,)
```

**EDIT 2:**

Print x_train and y_train contents

x_train

```
array([[[ 90.02,  91.5 ,  90.  ,  91.2 ],
        [ 91.28,  91.84,  90.98,  91.03],
        [ 91.96,  92.62,  90.91,  91.03],
        ...,
        [ 93.85,  94.66,  93.06,  93.17],
        [ 94.18,  95.38,  94.09,  95.34],
        [ 96.26,  96.32,  94.67,  95.68]],

       [[ 91.28,  91.84,  90.98,  91.03],
        [ 91.96,  92.62,  90.91,  91.03],
        [ 92.5 ,  93.95,  92.47,  93.46],
        ...,
        [ 94.18,  95.38,  94.09,  95.34],
        [ 96.26,  96.32,  94.67,  95.68],
        [ 95.34,  95.98,  94.71,  95.92]],

       [[ 91.96,  92.62,  90.91,  91.03],
        [ 92.5 ,  93.95,  92.47,  93.46],
        [ 93.85,  94.66,  93.06,  93.17],
        ...,
        [ 96.26,  96.32,  94.67,  95.68],
        [ 95.34,  95.98,  94.71,  95.92],
        [ 97.27,  99.96,  95.26,  95.48]],

       ...,

       [[120.35, 121.48, 118.92, 121.21],
        [121.65, 122.58, 120.73, 121.39],
        [120.11, 120.4 , 118.86, 119.9 ],
        ...,
        [123.66, 124.18, 122.49, 123.  ],
        [123.87, 126.16, 123.07, 125.9 ],
        [126.5 , 127.13, 125.65, 126.21]],

       [[121.65, 122.58, 120.73, 121.39],
        [120.11, 120.4 , 118.86, 119.9 ],
        [121.65, 123.52, 121.15, 122.15],
        ...,
        [123.87, 126.16, 123.07, 125.9 ],
        [126.5 , 127.13, 125.65, 126.21],
        [125.83, 127.92, 125.14, 127.9 ]],

       [[120.11, 120.4 , 118.86, 119.9 ],
        [121.65, 123.52, 121.15, 122.15],
        [123.66, 124.18, 122.49, 123.  ],
        ...,
        [126.5 , 127.13, 125.65, 126.21],
        [125.83, 127.92, 125.14, 127.9 ],
        [128.95, 130.39, 128.52, 130.36]]])
```

y_train

```
array([ 95.92,  95.48,  97.06,  97.73,  96.52,  96.33,  98.36,  97.  ,
        97.27,  92.85,  92.62,  94.81,  93.25,  95.04,  96.19, 106.26,
       108.94, 109.67, 110.06, 113.9 , 111.11, 112.73, 109.38, 113.01,
       115.01, 114.91, 114.61, 115.56, 115.71, 118.28, 124.37, 125.86,
       124.83, 126.52, 125.01, 124.81, 129.04, 134.18, 131.4 , 120.88,
       120.96, 112.82, 117.32, 113.49, 112.  , 115.36, 115.54, 112.13,
       110.34, 106.84, 110.08, 111.81, 107.12, 108.22, 112.28, 114.96,
       114.09, 115.81, 116.79, 113.02, 116.5 , 113.16, 115.08, 114.97,
       116.97, 124.4 , 121.1 , 121.19, 120.71, 119.02, 115.98, 117.51,
       116.87, 115.75, 115.04, 115.05, 116.6 , 111.2 , 115.32, 108.86,
       108.77, 110.44, 114.95, 119.03, 118.69, 116.32, 115.97, 119.49,
       119.21, 119.26, 120.3 , 119.39, 118.03, 118.64, 117.34, 113.85,
       115.17, 116.03, 116.59, 119.05, 122.72, 123.08, 122.94, 122.25,
       123.75, 124.38, 121.78, 123.24, 122.41, 121.78, 127.88, 127.81,
       128.7 , 126.66, 128.23, 131.88, 130.96, 131.97, 136.69, 134.87,
       133.72, 132.69, 129.41, 131.01, 126.6 , 130.92, 132.05, 128.98,
       128.8 , 130.89, 128.91, 127.14, 127.83, 132.03, 136.87, 139.07,
       142.92, 143.16, 142.06, 137.09, 131.96, 134.14, 134.99, 133.94,
       137.39, 136.76, 136.91, 136.01, 135.39, 135.13, 135.37, 133.19,
       130.84, 129.71, 129.87, 126.  , 125.86, 125.35, 120.99, 121.26,
       127.79, 125.12, 122.06, 120.13, 121.42, 116.36, 121.09, 119.98,
       121.96, 121.03, 123.99, 125.57, 124.76, 120.53, 119.99, 123.39,
       122.54, 120.09, 120.59, 121.21, 121.39, 119.9 , 122.15, 123.  ,
       125.9 , 126.21, 127.9 , 130.36, 133.  ])
```

Comment: Is your train/test dataset `x-train = (189, 7, 4)` or `x-train = numpy.reshape(x-train, (x-train.shape[0], 1, x-train.shape[1]))` ?

Comment: Hi Konata, I have updated my post. Please see the edited on how I obtain the dataset. Thank you!

Comment: You should delete last 4 line of code in your dataset part. It replace your x-train dataset to a 3 length data and y-train to 1 length data

Comment: Try to increase the batch size?

Comment: The last 4 lines should be correct. The inputs to the model has to be in this format from what I researched.

Comment: @tjysdsg Batch size increment result in same value still.

Comment: then i suggest you look at the content of x_train and y_train right before they are fed into the model, not just the shape.

Comment: @tjysdsg I don't see any foul play in both the dataset. Please see my revised post, I have posted the contents.

Comment: @SunnyJ hmm... then try using a very simple neural network with only fully connected layers. i haven't wrote keras code for quite a while now, but i suspect there might be something wrong with the net.

Comment: Also, it might be helpful to standardize x_train, since most of the values seem to be above 90. In addition, your x_train is quite small, so even if ur conv+lstm network definition is correct, it probably wont converge very well. In the worst case, the model learned nothing from the data so it outputs 120 for all samples. n fact, the mean of y_train is 120.20, very close to the network output. So it is likely the second case

Comment: @tjysdsg you are right. Normalizing it makes it work. Thank you.

Comment: @SunnyJ good to hear that!